Uploading files to Salesforce via external form is not working
There is an external form which allows Guest user to create a custom record using an LWC component.
A new requirement is to upload files/attachments and get that linked to created custom record.
We have enabled 'Allow site guest users to upload files', and implemented the code below after the form is submitted.
Scenario:

Guest user: External form allows to fill the details and on click of a submit, a Referral record gets inserted in salesforce..
After submission on the thank you page, there is a button 'Upload
files'.
Onclick which is expected to upload the file to salesforce as contentversion record and same gets linked to initially created referral record.
But onclick of 'Upload files' has no effect/No consoles.
Seems like 'onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}' is not called.

Any help is much appreciated
html:
<lightning-file-upload>
    label="Attach a file to the referral"
    name="fileUploader"
    accept={acceptedFormats}
    file-field-name='Guest_Record_fileupload__c'
    file-field-value={recordId}
    onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
    multiple
    >

JavaScript Controller:
handleUploadFinished(event) {
    console.log('Upload Complete');
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    console.log('--inside handleUploadFinished--'+uploadedFiles);
  // Apex call
}

[Modified as per this documentation][1]
So does Salesforce allows Guest users to upload files via external forms? If yes, can anybody help me to correct my code?
Performed all the steps according to the below documentation. But still same result!
[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read How to Ask. When you say that it isn't working, what exactly do you mean by that and what outputs are you getting in the console.log statements you have in the component? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

@CallumMacErlich, Thank you so much for the response, I have updated my question.

What is the data type of your Guest_Record_fileupload__c field?  If your file-field-value isn't the same data type, the upload will fail.
Also you have not set the record-id parameter in the component, so the file is not being attached to your referral record. See documentation.

Thanks for the response @david .
Guest_Record_fileupload__c is of type text(100).
i even tried with setting record-id but its same, bcz the process does not get as far as saving the record because the upload does not start at all - there is no response from the UI, so the save process is not initiated.
On choosing the file in 'Upload files' button, onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} is not executing.
